# An error occurred: 'Transcription' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, openai-api

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key="my_key")

audio_file_path ="C:/Users/name/OneDrive/VS Folder/speech.mp3"

with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
    try:
        transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(
            model="whisper-1", 
            file=audio_file
        )
        
        # Access the transcribed text
        transcribed_text = transcript['transcription']['text']
        
        # Print or do something with the transcribed text
        print(transcript)
        
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I'm expecting this code to transcribe the audio in audio file path, gettng error: An error occurred: 'Transcription' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please provide the full traceback

Comment: Try printing `transcript` to see what it really is.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick scan of [the documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription), it looks like the default return type from `OpenAI.audio.transcriptions.create` is JSON, which looks like a dict, but isn't. So you would have to convert that to a dict using `json.loads()`

```
transcription_result = json.loads(transcript)
transcription_text = transcription_result["text"]
```

Or, ask the API to return just the text with the `response_format='text' parameter.

```
transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(
            model="whisper-1", 
            file=audio_file,
            response_format='text'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this to access the text:

```
transcript.text
```

The response is an instance of the following:

```
class Transcription(BaseModel):
    text: str
```